# Blocking ports on the host for a bridge interface

Tags: iptables, proxmox

I run a Proxmox host where I have few KVM instances, using their own IP addresses (not NATed). Host has network card `eno1` which it's bridged to `vmbr0`. What I try to achieve, is to block port 22 to every KVM instance which access internet from `vmbr0`. I've tried to redirect `etables` rules to `iptables` but it has no effect.

Commands applied:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-filter-pppoe-tagged
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged
```

And then on iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i emo1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

But it has no effect for my VMs.

Any idea what I miss or I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> iptables -A INPUT -i emo1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
> ```

I'd figure that there's no interface named `emo1`? Should probably be `eno1` (**E**ther**N**et **O**nboard 1).

But, why not use the Proxmox VE firewall directly?

Enable it using the GUI in *Datacenter* -> *Firewall* -> *Options* and in *Node* -> *Firewall* -> *Options*

Then add a rule with the SSH macro and reject action on every VM's firewall panel.